# NGit/Nsch Generating SSH Keypair (c# Jgit)

Tags: jsch, jgit, ngit

I am wanting to generate a new keypair for use with Ngit (Jgit).

How do I generate a new keypair through code?

Answer (score 0):

JGit has JSch as dep, take a look at this example http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/KeyGen.java.html